# Pulling images from Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I upload full sized images to Amazon S3 from my rails app. Is there anyway to pull thumbnail sized versions instead of the full image as the images are quite large? Or do I have to also upload thumbnail sized images to be able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to store the sizes you want to retrieve on S3 or create an image server on S3 that will handle the resizing logic to serve the sizes you request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload the thumbnail images.